# icacls adding SID instead of friendly name

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, icacls

I need to apply the icacls command from a server in the network, for example, server001 to a folder that is on server002. The objective is to add a local security group  of server002 on a folder that is on that server, but run the command from the server001. Right now I have the following command:

```
icacls "\\server002\G$\permissionTest" /grant "The local group":(OI)(CI)RX
```

It applies the permissions, but in the ACL of the permissionTest folder on server002 I just see the SID of the group, and I need to see it on the friendly form.

Could someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: from where do you ask the permissions of the folder? If it's from a remote computer, that behaviour is logical, it does not know about the group/sid mapping. If from the remote computer the mapping is correct, then you're set

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what you're asking. Is it that you're trying to add an ACL to a folder on server2 using a local group from server2, but applied using the icacls command from server1?  Or are you trying to add a group from server1 onto a folder on server2?

Comment: I need to apply the permissions from server001, but the security group belongs to server002, and the folder that needs the permissions is on 002. This is for a script that I have to make, so I'm testing on this two servers first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue. I did this using the psexec tool, so you can run a command on a remote computer as if you were running it locally. I use the following syntax on the command:

```
psexec /accepteula \\server002 icacls G:\permissionTest /grant "Local server group":(OI)(CI)RX
```

I run this from server001 and it successfully applied the local group of server002 to the folder that is on server002 as well.